# How to automatically open several windows at startup on Debian

Tags: debian, terminal, bash-scripting, virtual-desktop

Is there any way to open several windows at startup (and possibly put them in two virtual desktops)? These include for example terminals (to be cd-ed at a specific directory each), file browser and web browser. Or maybe save the entire desktop status before shutting down, so that it is automatically restored at the next startup?

Thanks.